# Blueprint migration problems to JHipster 8

Tags: jhipster, yeoman, yeoman-generator, jhipster-blueprint

Hello JHipster community,

I have developed a simple blueprint that overrides certain Angular template files. The template worked fine for JHipster version 7.9.3.

Now I wanted to migrate this template to JHipster version 8. Unfortunately, I encountered a problem accessing generator methods within .ejs template files.

**Problem description:**

In my custom blueprint I extend the BaseApplicationGenerator of JHipster and try to replace the .ejs template file (*entityFile*.model.ts.ejs). Unfortunately, the following generator function is not found.

```
<% const enumImports = this.generateEntityClientEnumImports(fields); %>
```

This method call results in an error indicating the method cannot be found:

**Error message:**

```
ERROR! An error occured while running .blueprint:angular#writingEntitiesTemplateTask
    17|  limitations under the License.
    18| -%>
 >> 19| <%
    20| const enumImports = this.generateEntityClientEnumImports(fields);
    21| %>
    22| <%_ if (anyFieldIsDateDerived) { _%>

this.generateEntityClientEnumImports is not a function
```

**Attempted Solutions and Observations:**

- I confirmed the generateEntityClientEnumImports method exists and is properly defined within the context of the generator. (generator-jhipster\generators\angular\generator.ts)
- I tried to inherit from the AngularGenerator instead of the BaseApplicationGenerator
- to pass this.jhipsterContext instead of application

**New blueprint script for version 8.1.0:**

```
import BaseApplicationGenerator from 'generator-jhipster/generators/base-application';

export default class extends BaseApplicationGenerator {
    constructor(args, opts, features) {
        super(args, opts, {...features, sbsBlueprint: true});
    }

    get [BaseApplicationGenerator.WRITING]() {
        const ANGULAR_CLIENT_DIR = 'src/main/webapp/app';

        return this.asWritingTaskGroup({
            async writingTemplateTask({application}) {
                const templates = [
                    // date-german-formatter.ts
                    {
                        from: 'angular/src/main/webapp/app/config/date-german-formatter.ts.ejs',
                        to: `${ANGULAR_CLIENT_DIR}/config/date-german-formatter.ts`,
                    },
                    // font-awesome-icons.ts
                    {
                        from: 'angular/src/main/webapp/app/config/font-awesome-icons.ts.ejs',
                        to: `${ANGULAR_CLIENT_DIR}/config/font-awesome-icons.ts`,
                    },
                    // login.component.ts
                    {
                        from: 'angular/src/main/webapp/app/login/login.component.ts.ejs',
                        to: `${ANGULAR_CLIENT_DIR}/login/login.component.ts`,
                    },

            ...

                ];

                for (const {from, to} of templates) {
                    await this.fs.copyTpl(this.templatePath(from), this.destinationPath(to), application);
                }
            },
        });
    }

    get [BaseApplicationGenerator.WRITING_ENTITIES]() {
        const ANGULAR_ENTITIES_DIR = 'src/main/webapp/app/entities';
        const entities = this.jhipsterContext.localEntities;

        return this.asWritingEntitiesTaskGroup({
            async writingEntitiesTemplateTask({application}) {
                for (const entity of entities) {
                    const templates = [
                        {
                            from: `angular/${ANGULAR_ENTITIES_DIR}/_entityFile_.model.ts.ejs`,
                            to: `${ANGULAR_ENTITIES_DIR}/${entity.entityFolderName}/${entity.entityFileName}.model.ts`,
                        },
                
            ...

                    ];
                    for (const {from, to} of templates) {
                        await this.fs.copyTpl(this.templatePath(from), this.destinationPath(to), {
                            ...application,
                            ...entity,
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
        });
    }
}
```

**Old working script for v7.9.3:**

```
import EntityClientGenerator from 'generator-jhipster/esm/generators/entity-client';
import {PRIORITY_PREFIX, INITIALIZING_PRIORITY, WRITING_PRIORITY} from 'generator-jhipster/esm/priorities';

export default class extends EntityClientGenerator {
    constructor(args, opts, features) {
        super(args, opts, {taskPrefix: PRIORITY_PREFIX, ...features});

        if (this.options.help) {
            return;
        }

        if (!this.options.jhipsterContext) {
            throw new Error(`This is a JHipster blueprint and should be used only like 'jhipster --blueprints Test'`);
        }

        this.sbsBlueprint = true;
        this.context = this.options.jhipsterContext;
    }

    get [INITIALIZING_PRIORITY]() {
        return {
            async initializingTemplateTask() {
            },
        };
    }

    get [WRITING_PRIORITY]() {
        const ANGULAR_CLIENT_DIR = 'src/main/webapp/app/entities';

        return {
            async writingTemplateTask() {
               const templates = [
                        {
                            from: `angular/${ANGULAR_CLIENT_DIR}/entity.model.ts.ejs`,
                            to: `${ANGULAR_ENTITIES_DIR}/${this.context.entityFolderName}/${this.context.entityFileName}.model.ts`,
                        },
                
            ...

                    ];


                for (const { from, to } of templates) {
                    this.fs.copyTpl(
                        this.templatePath(from),
                        this.destinationPath(to),
                        this.context
                    );
                }
            },
        };
    }
}


und 

import ClientGenerator from 'generator-jhipster/esm/generators/client';
import {PRIORITY_PREFIX, INITIALIZING_PRIORITY, WRITING_PRIORITY} from 'generator-jhipster/esm/priorities';

export default class extends ClientGenerator {
    constructor(args, opts, features) {
        super(args, opts, {taskPrefix: PRIORITY_PREFIX, ...features});

        if (this.options.help) {
            return;
        }

        if (!this.options.jhipsterContext) {
            throw new Error(`This is a JHipster blueprint and should be used only like 'jhipster --blueprints test'`);
        }

        this.sbsBlueprint = true;
        this.context = this.options.jhipsterContext;
    }

    get [INITIALIZING_PRIORITY]() {
        return {
            async initializingTemplateTask() {
            },
        };
    }

    get [WRITING_PRIORITY]() {
        const ANGULAR_CLIENT_DIR = 'src/main/webapp/app';

        return {
            async writingTemplateTask() {
                 const templates = [
                    // date-german-formatter.ts
                    {
                        from: 'angular/src/main/webapp/app/config/date-german-formatter.ts.ejs',
                        to: `${ANGULAR_CLIENT_DIR}/config/date-german-formatter.ts`,
                    },
                    // font-awesome-icons.ts
                    {
                        from: 'angular/src/main/webapp/app/config/font-awesome-icons.ts.ejs',
                        to: `${ANGULAR_CLIENT_DIR}/config/font-awesome-icons.ts`,
                    },
                    // login.component.ts
                    {
                        from: 'angular/src/main/webapp/app/login/login.component.ts.ejs',
                        to: `${ANGULAR_CLIENT_DIR}/login/login.component.ts`,
                    },

            ...
                ];


                for (const { from, to } of templates) {
                    this.fs.copyTpl(
                        this.templatePath(from),
                        this.destinationPath(to),
                        this.context
                    );
                }
            },
        };
    }

}
```

Notably, in JHipster 8.1.0, internal changes seem to affect how generator contexts and methods are accessed within .ejs templates. However, the documentation and migration guides have not made it clear how to adjust for these changes. I would be grateful for any tips!